# Como coloco no meu site um arquivo para download com id único para cada pessoa que baixar

Tags: wordpress, button, link, download, plugin-wordpress

Como faço para colocar um arquivo para download me meu site no qual o link do botão muda sempre depois que o arquivo é baixado e nunca de para uma pessoa baixar pelo mesmo link que já foi baixado uma vez?

Uso o wordpress, ja vi isso em sites, mas não sei como fazer, tem como me ajudar?

Comment: Dá forma que está, sua pergunta é ampla, podes colocar o código que tens ? Você tem um entendimento em PHP ou Javascript ?

Comment: Nem da então porque não entendo muito de PHP ou js, pensei que tinha um código ou plugin que a gente só upa o arquivo ou cola uma url e pronto

Comment: Bom eu desconheço, talvez apareça alguém com mais experiência em WP que possa lhe indicar 1, boa sorte.

Comment: Marcio, o site é só sobre programação mesmo, indicação de plugin não cabe no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Mas mesmo fechando a questão como fora de escopo, os comentários continuam abertos se alguém tiver uma dica pra te dar. Se você tentar aprender o básico para fazer alguma coisa e tiver dúvida, acho que o site vai ser mais útil pra te ajudar.

Comment: Na verdade, creio que nem deva ser necessário um nível avançado para resolver seu problema, talvez se encontrar no código, o html referente a esse botão e editar sua questão, passando mais informações dê para salvar... é que tá meio confuso o que está querendo fazer, pelo menos eu não estou entendendo... talvez um exemplo..

Comment: Usando DB vc consegue seu intento!

Comment: DB seria o dropbox? Se for não da

Comment: É bem isso que eu procuro, vou aprender php

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo por que você não coloca isso como resposta ? Parece responder bem a pergunta... Assim outros usuários como dúvida semelhante poderiam se beneficiar...

Comment: ok vou postar os codigos na resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A idéia é criar uma tabela com um campo unicoid.

Uma pagina que vai inserir $chave = uniqid(md5(rand())); no campo unicoid e gerar um link download.php?id=".$chave

Na página de download obter a chave do banco de dados igual ao valor do parâmetro id. Se existir, forçar o navegador a fazer o download e imediatamente dar um delete no campo unicoid.

**downloadkey.php**

```
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "DB");

if(empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
}

$url = preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$folderpath = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.ltrim(dirname($url), '/').'/';

$key = uniqid(md5(rand()));

$time = date('U');

echo "<p>Download link: <a href=\"" . $folderpath . "download.php?id=" . $key . "\">Baixar</a></p>";
echo "<p><span class=\"box\">" . $folderpath . "download.php?id=" . $key . "</span></p>";


$sqli = ("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES(\"$key\",\"$time\")");
$result= mysqli_query($link,$sqli);

mysqli_close($link);
```

**Download.php**

```
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "DB");

if (!$link) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = ("SELECT * FROM downloadkey Where uniqueid='".$_GET['id']."'");
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $arquivo = 'arquivo.zip';
    header('Content-type: octet/stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$arquivo.'";'); 
    readfile($arquivo);
    $sql = ("DELETE FROM downloadkey Where uniqueid='".$_GET['id']."'");
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    exit;
}else{
    echo "<p>Link de download que você está usando é inválido.";
    echo "<br><a href=\"downloadkey.php\">Clique aqui para obter novo link de download</a></p>";
}

mysqli_close($link);
```